# Auto generate c code in gVim

Tags: vim

In a ***.c** file in gVim, when I type `for(` I want Vim to generate rest of the basic *for loop* structure as below.

```
for(;;)
{
}
```

I have achieved this with the help of the following abbreviation in _vimrc.

```
ab for( for(;;)<CR>{<CR>}
```

But, I want this abbreviation to be active only in a `c` file.

Is there a condition I can use in `_vimrc` so that the abbreviation is disabled in all the files but in ***.c** file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One good way to achieve this with vim is by the use of `autocommand`, for instance with:

```
autocmd FileType c      abb <buffer> for( for(;;)<CR>{<CR>}
```

`autocommand` is really powerful, and the [documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html) is quite good.
In this example, be careful to use `abb` with the `<buffer>` parameter, since you want this abbreviation to be active only on the c source file buffer. See [abbreviate-local](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:abbreviate-local) documentation for example.

Comment: I've used abb, but I don't see the desired result. I mean, when I've *.c and *.txt file in buffer, this ab is enabled in *.txt file as well...

Comment: I believe its `abbreviate <buffer>`, `ab` and `abb` are just the short forms of `abbreviate`

Comment: `abb` is a short for for `abbreviate-local`, which defines an abbreviation that is active only for the current buffer, thus interesting in combination with `autocmd`, see http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:abbreviate-local

Comment: There is no command called `:abbreviate-local`. The way you do local abbreviations is with `:abbreviate <buffer>`

Comment: Thanks @FDinoff, I did misunderstand the documentation. Corrected the answer.

Answer (score 6):

This feature is usually called "snippets".

It is supported by various Vim plugins like [SirVer/ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips)